# Joining two tables on interval basis

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, suppose that I have table A

```
ID
--
1
3
5
```

and table B

```
ID2
---
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

To get the result similar to:

```
ID |  ID2
----------
1  |  1
1  |  2
3  |  3
3  |  4
5  |  5
5  |  6
```

For an explanation, an element in column ID2 will be mapped to the highest value in the column ID that is less than or equal to the said element in ID2.

For example, 4 in column ID2 is mapped to 3 from column ID, because 3 is the largest value in column ID which is less than or equal to 4.

Is it possible at all to do this in sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is start by joining the two tables on the condition that the id in the first table is less than or equal to that in the second table, like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id AS id2
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.id >= t1.id;
```

Once you have that, you can select the maximum id from the first table, and group by the id from the second table to get the largest pairs:

```
SELECT MAX(t1.id) AS id, t2.id AS id2
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.id >= t1.id
GROUP BY t2.id;
```

SQL Fiddle seems to be down but I will update with a link as soon as I can.

Comment: Do you know a specific name to this problem? It beats me on how should I name my own problem.

Comment: To be honest, no. I'm not sure there is.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(A.ID) ID, B.ID2
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.ID2 >= A.ID
GROUP BY B.ID2
```

Comment: Could the downvoter explain? My answer is the same as the accepted answer (and was posted sooner).

Comment: no idea about the downvote, but +1 for having this up a few minutes after the question was posted and getting overlooked

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the matching ID column:

```
select b.*,
  (select max(ID) from a where a.ID <= b.ID2) as a_Id
from b
```

If you need more columns:

```
select *
from a
join
 (
   select b.*,
     (select max(ID) from a where a.ID <= b.ID2) as a_Id
   from b
 ) as b
on a.Id = b.a_Id
```